# Read single varible from txt file each time processing multiple files using pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis, file-processing

I stored a calculated variable in another file let's say A.txt as follows:

```
123
1123
123
123
123
...
```

I want to use single variable each time from file A.txt (sequentially) when each acb.*  read by pandas, processing acb.* multiples files that I was doing as follows using pandas:
(how do I read acb.* file in numeric order like 1 then 2 and so on?)

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import glob
  for filename in sorted(glob.glob('acb.*')): 
  with open(filename) as f:
    df = pd.read_table(f, sep=" ", skiprows=2)
```

How to combine this two task simultaneously? I know we can read two files at single time in pandas but how do I use single variable from file A.txt each time when I read a acb.* file sequentially?

Comment: are you looking to concatenate the two dfs?

Comment: "How to combine this two task simultaneously?" what two tasks? Your question is completely unclear, at least to me.

Comment: not really, I will be procesing acb.* files (sequentially) and for that I need to use a data from A.txt file line by line. So it like use 123 for acb.1 and 1123 for acb.2 ..

Comment: create a list and loop within the list?

Comment: Then it will not simultaneous.

Comment: How you want to incorporate the data from A.txt into the dataframe?

Comment: I need those data for performing some data processing on acb files

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understood your question fully but you can read the data into pandas df, and then looping through each row while looping through each line of the abc file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

df = pd.read_table(f, sep=" ", skiprows=2)

for filename in sorted(glob.glob('acb.*')): 
    with open(filename) as f:
       for row in df.itertuples():
       print(row.column1)
       print(row.Index)
       #do tasks
```